# jQuery form plug in with Box.net

Tags: jquery, box-api

does anyone use jquery form plugin with Box.net cloud storage. At the moment, I am struggling to upload a file to box.net using jquery form plugin.

My Javascript code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#uploadForm').ajaxForm({
            beforeSubmit:   function() { alert('before');},
            success:        function(data) { alert('success: ' );},
            url:            'https://upload.box.net/api/1.0/upload/token/183331021',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType:       'xml',
            crossDomain: true
        });
    });
```

My page:

```
<form id="uploadForm" name="uploadForm" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label>File to upload</label>
  <input type="file" size="30" name="file" id="fileToUpload"/>  
  <input type="text" value="hello"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload"></input>
</form>
```

It seems that the success function never got run, does anybody have any idea of what might be causing this?

Comment: Is there an error callback you can use? Wouldn't mind betting that there is and you're getting an error in there.

Comment: Looks like *Same origin policy* - AJAX won't work for external domains. You'll have to use server side requests.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512529/upload-files-to-the-cloud-from-web-application) it confirms my previous assumption.

Comment: Hi guys, after some research, I don't think any ajax file upload plugin would work. The way ajax file upload work is using hidden iframe to get response from server. Due to cross domain restriction, javascript can't get access to the hidden iframe content if it is in different domain.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax does not work across different domains.  It's a "security feature" of JavaScript.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

A possible fix is to mirror the Ajax post via a relative server side request which then will relay it to your https box address above.  I've done this using Perl and ASP.Net, but it can be done with others too.